# Yii2 GridView show multiple pages

Tags: php, yii2

I have a GridView with 52 rows and two columns.

What I want is instead of a 52-row long list, to have four lists, one next to the other, each with 13 rows, so like pagination with pageSize=13 but have all pages visible one next to the other.

Can anyone point me to the right direction?

Comment: Instead of [this](http://imgur.com/uBICRgp), I want [this](http://imgur.com/2zYYczC). I created this on GIMP to better showcase what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be use different dataProvider with different page values

```
$dataProvider0 = new ActiveDataProvider([
  ...
  'pagination' => [
    'pageSize' => 13,
    'page' = 0,
  ],
]);

$dataProvider1 = new ActiveDataProvider([
  ...
  'pagination' => [
    'pageSize' => 13,
    'page' = 1,
  ],
]);

$dataProvider2 = new ActiveDataProvider([
  ...
  'pagination' => [
    'pageSize' => 13,
    'page' = 2,
  ],
]);

$dataProvider3 = new ActiveDataProvider([
  ...
  'pagination' => [
    'pageSize' => 13,
    'page' = 3,
  ],
]);
```

And assigning the provider to 4 different gridview

Comment: Simple and to the point! Thank you, this works!
Sad to admit that I was stuck 2 days on this...

Answer (score 0):

There are several possible solutions.

1. You can use GridView properties `$beforeRow` and `$afterRow` to visually split one GridView to several blocks.
2. You can use one instance of the DataProvider to split it to several ones. For example, you can use an ActiveDataProvider and make `$provider->getModels()` to get all model objects. Then create four instances of ArrayDataProvider and just use them in four GridViews.